# How to import a text file with no delimiters with 2 lines representing a case

Tags: mysql, text-files, data-import

I have several text files that I need to import into MySQL, but they don't have any delimiters, and 3 lines in the text file represent one record.
When I try to import it everything goes into one column. Please see an example below

```
00003461020000001ACH1                             00000000 00000000000  00000000                                                                                          000000005011025708084                                                                                                                                                       0                                                                                                                               00                                                                                                                                00                                        000000000000000000000                                                                                                                                                          00000000241523551MA00
```

Comment: Please better explain your example, and what you would want to obtain.
You said 3 lines of text represent one record, but I don't see 3 lines in your example.

Comment: Please post the following details: sample file, records that you want to get in db, and please format them as `code`.

Comment: Hi guys please find attached a link with the sample file

https://cl01.za.dc.cloudology.co.za/f/ee5754ee85/

Comment: And what shall we do with the sample file? What's the problem? Also almost noone is willing to click on random links here and all information necessary for the question should be included in the question here on SO. Include the necessary sample data in the question, describe what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a helper table first.

```
CREATE TABLE tmpHelperTable(
your_data varchar(255),
a int, 
b int
);
```

Then you need two [user defined variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html) while loading your data.

```
SET @va = 0;
SET @vb = 0;

LOAD DATA INFILE 'your_data_file.csv'
INTO tmpHelperTable
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(your_data, a, b)
SET a = @va := IF(@va = 3, 1, @va + 1),
b = IF(@va % 3 = 0, @vb := @vb + 1, @vb);
```

This line

```
SET a = @va := IF(@va = 3, 1, @va + 1),
```

is just an incrementing value, that resets when it reaches 3 (or whatever many lines determine one case).
The line

```
b = IF(@va = 1, @vb := @vb + 1, @vb);
```

just increments its value every time the previous variable got reset. We need this so we can `group by` it. Then you have a table like this:

```
your_data  |  a  |  b
xxxxxx        1     1
yyyyyy        2     1
zzzzzz        3     1
aaaaaa        1     2
bbbbbb        2     2
cccccc        3     2
dddddd        1     3
...
```

Then all you have to do is to pivot the table into your final table.

```
CREATE TABLE final_table(
id int,
data_1 varchar(255),
data_2 varchar(255),
data_3 varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO final_table
SELECT
b, 
MAX(IF(a = 1, your_data, NULL)),
MAX(IF(a = 2, your_data, NULL)),
MAX(IF(a = 3, your_data, NULL)),
FROM 
tmpHelperTable
GROUP BY b;
```